# How to Convert String into Date Java

Tags: java, string, list, parsing, date

I currently have an `ArrayList` filled with dates in the format `2012-06-19` and I am trying to add them all to an array of `Date`s.

This is the portion of code that is failing me,

```
    listIterator = dateValues.listIterator();

    Date [] dates = new Date[dateValues.size()];
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    int i = 0;
    try{
        while(listIterator.hasNext())
        {
            //System.out.println(listIterator.next().toString());
            dates[i] =  dateFormat.parse(listIterator.next().toString());
            i++;

        }

        for(i = 0; i < dates.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(dates[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace()};
}
```

The line

```
//System.out.println(listIterator.next().toString());
```

will print out every date in the ArrayList. Output looks like,

```
2007-09-07
2007-09-07
2007-10-05
2007-10-05
2007-10-05
2007-10-05
2007-10-05
```

but my `dateFormat` line never adds any values to `dates[]`. Any help would be appreciated.

And no, it isn't homework.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the strings you have in dateValues?

Comment: I doubt it throws exception which is caught and go unnoticed, Check the format  of String

Comment: You should **NEVER** catch a exception and ignore it unless you have a good reason. At least print it out.

Comment: If you uncomment that line you are calling `next()` twice in a single iteration, which will eventually result in `NoSuchElementException` being thrown.

Comment: Hey, just added example output of the System.out.println(), I have an e.printStackTrace() I just never wrote it here sorry.

Comment: How do you know it never adds any values to `dates`? Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: I have a for loop after this code which should print all the members of dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> dateValues = new ArrayList<String>();
Date[] dates = new Date[dateValues.size()];
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
int i = 0;
for (String dateValue : dateValues) {
    dates[i++] = dateFormat.parse(dateValue);
}
```

"Less code is good", so use the language (foreach loops etc) to keep your code small and clean (like the code above).

Note to pedants before you comment: "less code is good", as long as it remains readable.

Answer (score 1):

If the line:

```
//System.out.println(listIterator.next().toString());
```

is uncommented `next()` is called twice in a single iteration, which will eventually result in `NoSuchElementException` being thrown. Meaning that the subsequent `for` loop will not be executed. Store the result of `next()`:

```
while(listIterator.hasNext())
{
    String s = listIterator.next().toString();
    System.out.println(s);
    dates[i] = dateFormat.parse(s);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Still no dice man, the dates get printed out alright but nothing gets added to `dates[]`

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @Tom Celic, works for me.

```
List<String> dateValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    dateValues.add("2012-09-08");
    dateValues.add("2011-09-08");
    Date[] dates = new Date[dateValues.size()];
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    int i = 0;
    for (String dateValue : dateValues) {
        dates[i++] = dateFormat.parse(dateValue);
    }
    System.out.println(dates.length);
    System.out.println(dates[0]);
    System.out.println(dates[1]);
```

It prints:

```
    2
Sat Sep 08 00:00:00 IST 2012
Thu Sep 08 00:00:00 IST 2011
```